# Volume inside $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$.

Tags: volume, jacobian

Let's say I'm trying to find the volume inside $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$. Can I go about defining new variables $X=x^2,Y=y^2,Z=z^2$ so that we know have a unit sphere in $X,Y,Z$. Then computing the Jacobian of this inverse transformation to be $(2x)(2y)(2z)=8xyz$. So that the Jacobian corresponding to this transformation is $\frac{1}{8xyz}$ and then I need to compute:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{|8\rho^3 \sin (\phi)^2 \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) \cos (\phi)|} \rho^2 \sin(\phi)\ \mathrm d\rho\ \mathrm d\phi\ \mathrm d\theta$$

Would that work?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The integral evaluates to $0$.

Comment: I think because I forgot absolute value but then again there is a division by $0$ problem @user170231

Comment: see my answer to [a generalized version of this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/301506/59379). I remember aside this, there are other similar questions but I can't find them.

Comment: $X, Y, Z \ge 0$ which means that that this will work when $\phi, \theta$ are in the first octant.  $\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\int_0^1 \frac {4}{\rho\sin2\phi\sin2\theta} d\rho\;d\phi\;\;d\theta$ should work.

Comment: Thanks that clears everything up! @DougM

Comment: I multiplied by 8 (because we are evaluating over the first octant instead of the full region)  and then $\sin\theta\cos\theta$ becomes $\frac 12 \sin2\theta$ but what happens to those $\frac 12$ terms in the denominator?