# Area Enclosed by $x^{2n} +y^{2n}=2n$

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions

Recently I was just playing with the idea of shapes with higher coefficients of x and y.

Using Desmos, I plotted graphs of the form $x^{2n}+ y^{2n} = 1$ All these of,course pass through the four points $\{(1,0),(0,1),(0,-1),(-1,0)\}$.

As one increases the value of $n$, The graph sort of pushes towards the lines  $x,y=1,-1$. This is reasonable as none of the variables can actually exceed unity.

But when instead of 1 we define the shape as $x^{2n}+ y^{2n} = 2n$, the graph bulges outwards, but with increasing values of $n$, shrinks back, visually and intuitively I think the area enclosed by the graph would become 4 as ${n\to \infty} $. But I could not mathematically prove it using integration or otherwise.

Also, is there any name for such shapes and do we use them anywhere for some practical benefits?
And can we manipulate the graphs to change the vertices of the limiting "square", if there is one?

PS: Just to clarify my knowledge base: I am a Class 12th student in India and preparing for JEE ADVANCED, so I am familiar with basic concepts of finding areas using calculus.

Comment: These are the unit spheres of the [$p$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) on $\Bbb{R}^2$, where $p = 2n$. The figure does indeed approach a square (in a certain sense), though the area enclosed approaches $4$, not $1$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Not the unit sphere when the RHS is $2n$ instead of $1$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for pointing out the error, how could someone prove that the area is in fact approached to 4 ?

Comment: @Hardik I don't know an elementary proof personally (I think there would be one), but there is a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301506/hypervolume-of-a-n-dimensional-ball-in-p-norm) about the area/volume/measure of a general unit ball of the $p$-norm.

Comment: These things are called superellipses. The Wikipedia page has some info about them, including their areas:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

Comment: @bubba Thanks for the article, it was an interesting read.

Comment: You should probably read and understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem  
Alternately, you can try Archimedes technique https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle  
I don't think you're ready for it, but you could also apply "Differential Geometry".  Which has direct methods, but the formulas are not necessarily simple.

Comment: @rrogers I did read and understood Archimedes Technique, Thanks for the link to the Divergence Theorem, although I could not fully grasp it, it sure was insightful.

Comment: Thanks for the response: The original "modern" basis stems from "Gauss's divergance theorem.  It simply implies that the change of area can be computed by on the perimeter; changing a double summation (integral) to a single one(perimeter).  Your first introduction will probably be "the curl" of a vector field (say area).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Basic Problem**

In the first quadrant, the curve
$$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}
x^{2n}+y^{2n}=1\tag1
$$
can be parametrized by
$$
(x,y)=\left(\cos(t)^{1/n},\sin(t)^{1/n}\right)\tag2
$$

[image]

The area inside the curve is
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}(x,y)\times(x,y)'\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}(x,y)\times(x,y)'\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3a}\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\cos(t)^{1/n},\sin(t)^{1/n}\right)\times\left(\cos(t)^{1/n},\sin(t)^{1/n}\right)'\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3b}\\
&=\frac2n\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(t)^{1/n-1}\cos(t)^{1/n-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3c}\\
&=\frac2n\int_0^1t^{1/n-1}\left(1-t^2\right)^{\frac{1-n}{2n}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\tag{3d}\\
&=\frac1n\int_0^1t^{\frac{1-2n}{2n}}(1-t)^{\frac{1-2n}{2n}}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3e}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac1{2n}\right)}{n\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac1n\right)}\tag{3f}\\
&=\frac{4\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1n\right)}\tag{3g}\\
&=4-\frac{\pi^2}{6n^2}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\tag{3h}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: the area is $4$ times the area in the first quadrant
$\text{(3b)}$: apply $(2)$
$\text{(3c)}$: compute the cross product
$\text{(3d)}$: substitute $t\mapsto\arcsin(t)$
$\text{(3e)}$: substitute $t\mapsto t^{1/2}$
$\text{(3f)}$: Beta integral
$\text{(3g)}$: $\Gamma\!\left(\frac1n\right)=n\,\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1n\right)$
$\text{(3h)}$: $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$, $\Gamma''(1)=\frac{\pi^2}6+\gamma^2$

This converges pretty quickly to the square. The area outside the curve but inside the square is approximately $\frac{\pi^2}{6n^2}$.

---

**Adjusting the Scales**

In the first quadrant, the curve
$$
x^{2n}+y^{2n}=2n\tag4
$$
can be parameterized by
$$
(x,y)=(2n)^{\frac1{2n}}\left(\cos(t)^{1/n},\sin(t)^{1/n}\right)\tag5
$$

[image]

That is, each coordinate has been scaled by $(2n)^{\frac1{2n}}$. This means the area has been scaled by $(2n)^{1/n}$. The area inside the curve is
$$
\begin{align}
(2n)^{1/n}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac1{2n}\right)}{n\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac1n\right)}
&=(2n)^{1/n}\frac{4\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1n\right)}\tag{6a}\\
&=4+\frac{4\log(2n)}{n}+\frac{2\log(2n)^2}{n^2}-\frac{\pi^2}{6n^2}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)^3}{n^3}\right)\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$
This converges much more slowly to the square; the amount of area outside the square and inside the curve is approximately $\frac{4\log(2n)}{n}$.

---

**Details on Computing the Area**

The triangle with sides $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is half of the parallelogram generated by $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, so we can compute its area as half of the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Geometric_meaning):
$$
\frac12\det\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}=\frac12(ad-bc)\tag7
$$
We can also compute the area of the triangle by setting it as the base for a [prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry)) with height $1$; generated by $(a,b,0)$, $(c,d,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$, and with volume computed using a [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Geometric_interpretation):
$$
\frac12(a,b,0)\times(c,d,0)\cdot(0,0,1)=\frac12(ad-bc)\tag8
$$
Because of this and the fact that it is an antisymmetric bilinear form, the quantity
$$
(a,b)\times(c,d)=ad-bc\tag9
$$
is sometimes called a cross-product, even though it is a scalar and not a vector.

By summing up triangular pieces of the area

[image]

we get the area of the closed curve traced out by $\vec{v}$ to be
$$
\frac12\oint\vec{v}\times\mathrm{d}\vec{v}\tag{10}
$$
In $(3)$, we have $\vec{v}=\left(\cos(t)^{1/n},\sin(t)^{1/n}\right)$, so expanding $\text{(3c)}$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(\cos(t)^{1/n},\sin(t)^{1/n}\right)\times\left(\cos(t)^{1/n},\sin(t)^{1/n}\right)'\\
&=\left(\cos(t)^{1/n},\sin(t)^{1/n}\right)\times\frac1n\left(-\sin(t)\cos(t)^{1/n-1},\cos(t)\sin(t)^{1/n-1}\right)\tag{11a}\\
&=\frac1n\,\sin(t)^{1/n}\cos(t)^{1/n}\left(\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin(t)}+\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}\right)\tag{11b}\\
&=\frac1n\,\sin(t)^{1/n-1}\cos(t)^{1/n-1}\tag{11c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(11a)}$: take the derivative
$\text{(11b)}$: evaluate the cross product, pulling out a common factor
$\text{(11c)}$: $\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin(t)}+\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}=\frac1{\sin(t)\cos(t)}$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer,  could you provide some reference to study (Or the name of) the technique you have used to integrate the expression after the parametrizing the curve, the cross product part. The transition 3b to 3c.

Comment: @Hardik: I have added some explanation. If you need more, please let me know.

Comment: this was probably the finest way to explain the method, thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 6):

I can assume that you want to prove that
$x=1,y=1,x=-1,y=-1$ are asymptotic boundaries of your curve (when $n \to \infty$) for $|x|,|y| \leq 1$

Take

$$ x^{2n}=2n-y^{2n} $$

$$ x=\pm \sqrt[2n]{2n-y^{2n}}$$

First we know that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac1{n}}=1$$
Equally
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n \pm 1)^{\frac1{n}}=1$$

This is to say

$$ x=\pm\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{2n-y^{2n}}=\pm 1$$

The same if you take

$$ y=\pm \sqrt[2n]{2n-x^{2n}}$$

$$ y=\pm\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[2n]{2n-x^{2n}}=\pm 1$$

That is for $|x|,|y| \leq 1$. Now you need to prove that we cannot have $|x|,|y| > 1$ at infinity. But this is not possible for the same reasoning as above that claims that it is strictly $|x|,|y| = 1$ at infinity. It would have to exist one point where both $|x|>1$ and $|y|>1$. However, none of the approaching curves (when $2n < +\infty$) has this property. Therefore, its asymptote cannot have this property either.

The conclusion about the asymptotic area follows.

You could attack the area directly but the reasoning is more or less the same.

$$S_{n}=2\int_{-1-\delta}^{1+\delta}\sqrt[\frac{1}{2n}]{2n-x^{2n}}dx$$

However, we have just confirmed that $\delta \to 0$ and $\sqrt[\frac{1}{2n}]{2n-x^{2n}} \to 1$ as $n \to +\infty$. It is giving

$$S_{\infty}=2\int_{-1}^{1}dx=4$$

Answer (score 0):

method of Dirichlet, in Whittaker and Watson, the area is

$$ \frac{ 4 \; (2n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \; \Gamma \left(1 + \frac{1}{2n}  \right)^2  }   { \Gamma \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}  \right) } $$

When $n=1$  we need to know $ \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2}  \right) = \frac {\sqrt \pi }{2}. $ In this case we have a circle of radius $\sqrt 2,$  area is $2 \pi $